# Habilitar y deshabilitar Textbox C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo un formulario con los siguientes campos, el problema es que no encuentro cuál es el error por que no me bloquea los textbox del primer botón y las que están en el segundo botón si los bloquea, se supone que es realizar lo mismo para lo demás,los datos son los mismos en las dos secciones.

```
  protected void btncomprobar2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     if (txtnom.Text != "")
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select d_direccion,d_edad,d_ciudad from Personal where d_nombres='" + txtnom.Text + "'", conn);
            conn.Open();
     try
            {
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (dr.Read() == true)
                {
                    lblmensaje.Text = "";
                    txtdir.Enabled = true;
                    txtedad.Enabled = true;
                    txtciud.Enabled = true;
                    txtdir.Text = dr["d_direccion"].ToString();
                    txtedad.Text = dr["d_edad"].ToString();
                    txtciud.Text = dr["d_ciudad"].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    lblmensaje.Text = "Nombre invalido";
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
}
  protected void btncomprobar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if (txtnom.Text != "")
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select d_direccion,d_edad,d_ciudad from Personal where d_nombres='" + txtnom.Text + "'", conn);
            conn.Open();

     try
            {
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (dr.Read() == true)
                {
                    lblmensaje.Text = "";
                    txtdir.Enabled = true;
                    txtedad.Enabled = true;
                    txtciud.Enabled = true;
                    txtdir.Text = dr["d_direccion"].ToString();
                    txtedad.Text = dr["d_edad"].ToString();
                    txtciud.Text = dr["d_ciudad"].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    lblmensaje.Text = "Nombre invalido";
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
 }
```

Comment: Amigo, publica el código **html**

Comment: No tengo código html amigo sólo lo hice con ése código en ASP.NET C#

Answer (score 4):

Es bastante simple el porque te bloquea solo unos campos:

```
                lblmensaje.Text = "";
                txtdir.Enabled = true;
                txtedad.Enabled = true;
                txtciud.Enabled = true;
                txtdir.Text = dr["d_direccion"].ToString();
                txtedad.Text = dr["d_edad"].ToString();
                txtciud.Text = dr["d_ciudad"].ToString();
```

Tienes esas lineas de códigos en ambos eventos `clic`, siempre esta bloqueando los mismo controles, supongo que se deben llamar diferente los `text` de arriba y los de abajo, tienes usar el nombre que les corresponde.

En la pantalla tienes 8 `textbox`, aunque se vean igual, para `ASP` son objetos diferentes, cada uno debe tener su propio `id` (nombre especifico)...

En los eventos clic que pones con el código `botonComprobar` y `botonComprobar2` siempre modificas los mismos 4 objetos(`textbox`), revisa bien el nombre de los `textbox` y modifica con el nombre correcto.

En el evento `botonComprobar2` deberías tener algo como:

```
                lblmensaje2.Text = "";
                txtdir2.Enabled = true;
                txtedad2.Enabled = true;
                txtciud2.Enabled = true;
                txtdir2.Text = dr["d_direccion2"].ToString();
                txtedad2.Text = dr["d_edad2"].ToString();
                txtciud2.Text = dr["d_ciudad2"].ToString();
```

Comment: Ya supe cúal fue el problema, pequeño error de programación, Gracias!

Comment: @MarthA.No te olvides de marcar la respuesta como correcta si el comentario resolvió tu duda